# Add it at end of page

Tags: javascript, html, c#-4.0

I want to add a button at end of the number of rows in table is equal to 5.
I wrote something like this:

```
<div class="right-side">
  <div class="log-in" style="height:1100px">
    <div class="title clearfix">
      <p>Gallery</p>
    </div>
    <form id="ab" name="ab">
      <div style="float:left;width:190px">
        <table id ="myTable">
          @foreach(var g in @ViewBag.gallery)
          {
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-right :50px"><img src="@g.imgpath" style="width:200px;height:200px"/></td>
            <td style="padding-left :50px"><div class="side-row"><a>@g.idescr</a></div></td>
            <td style="padding-left :50px"><a class="button" href="#"><img src='../images/chg-img.png'/></a></td>
          </tr>
        }
      </table>
      <script>var rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length;
        if(rowCount==5) 
        {
          var element = document.createElement("input");
          element.setAttribute("type", "file");
          element.setAttribute("class", "button");
          element.setAttribute("name", "button3");
          document.ab.appendChild(element);      
        }
      </script>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>  
</div>
```

But the child adding at start of page,Why?

Comment: Do you want to add it after the form? or after the 5th rown in the table?

Comment: Ya after the 5th row of table....

Comment: Modified my code to something like this. <tr><td></td><td></td><td>
           <script>var rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length;
               if(rowCount==6) 
               {
still not working
                   var element = document.createElement("input");
                   element.setAttribute("type", "file");
                   element.setAttribute("class", "button");
                   element.setAttribute("name", "button3");
                   alert("last");
                   document.ab.appendChild(element);
               }
           </script>
                </td></tr></table>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do this:

```
</tr>
     }
     </table>
     @if(ViewBag.gallery.Count == 5){
         <input ......./>
      }
```

Comment: Thank you very much.This of solution i am looking for my problem.But i don't know that function and tried for that table rows thing.Once again Thank you

Comment: Adding this in the correct place, but I think what you want will achieve this:  <form id="ab" name="ab"><div id="content" style="float:left;width:190px">        document.getElementById("content").appendChild(element);

Answer (score 2):

Instead of appending to the form try:

```
$("#myTable").parent().append(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have jquery, try the follwing:

replace:

```
var rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length;
       if(rowCount==5) 
       {
           var element = document.createElement("input");
           element.setAttribute("type", "file");
           element.setAttribute("class", "button");
           element.setAttribute("name", "button3");
           document.ab.appendChild(element);      
       }
```

With:

```
$("#myTable tr").eq(4).after( $('<input/>', { "type": "file", "name": "button3"}).addClass("button"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like

HTML

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("<input type='file'/>").insertAfter($('table#myTable tr:nth-child(5)'))
});
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaasthana/xwqSt/)